# Recursive DNS server answers with CNAME but does not return the A record

Tags: linux, dns, bind, cname, recursion

I have a recursive DNS server that forwards to my primary DNS servers in order to get a resolution.

Take the example

I have the below CNAME:

```
server1.example1.com.    300     IN      CNAME   server1.example2.com
```

And the relevant A:

```
server1.example2.com     IN     A    X.X.X.X
```

The problem I’m facing is that the recursive server is returning only the CNAME record when I do a `dig` and does not answer for the A record. I have verified through a TCP dump that the primaries are definitely returning the CNAME & A records to the recursive, but it in turn does not return them to the `dig` command or any client pointing to that server. I have other recursive name servers and it works fine. But to note it seems to only happen for cross-domain CNAMES

```
    bash-4.1# dig @recurisveserver server1.example1.com.                                      

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5 <<>> @recurisveserver server1.example1.com.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49412
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server1.example1.com.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
server1.example1.com.    300     IN      CNAME   server1.example2.com.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.73.241.88#53(10.73.241.88)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar  5 15:52:31 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```

Nslookup gives a blank response

```
    > server1.example1.com
Server:  recursiveserver
Address:  x.x.x.x

Name:    server1.example1.com
```

Comment: [Don't obfuscate what you are publishing to the world anyway](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html).  People cannot check it out for themselves and tell you what is happening.  You also need to tell people what the proxy DNS server software is that is behaving this way, and how you have set it up.  There _are_ possible explanations for this, but there's not anywhere near enough proper information in the question to determine that they are the right answers for the situation at hand.

Comment: You'll need to tell people the IP address, too.  Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417101/ for just one example of a question that includes the all-important unobfuscated correct IP address that turned out to be the key to the answer.

Comment: "Proxy DNS server" does not apply - the OP is using BIND to do authorative and recursive DNS.

Comment: [Being a resolving proxy DNS server _is_ proxy DNS service](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-server-roles.html).

Answer (score -1):

This all looks correct to me. A CNAME points to another domain name - but it's up to the client to do a second lookup to convert the returned CNAME into an A record - thus you would not expect dig or nslookup to return an IP address.

Comment: Thanks David, So when when i dig using the same command the only thing different is that im digging @working recursive server i get the proper answer back with cname and A record `;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server1.example1.com.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
server1.example1.com. 592  IN      CNAME   server1.example2.com.
server1.example2.com. 1200 IN     A       10.x.x.x .......... Also nslookup on the client returns the a record and the resolution works perfect. So i believe it should return the A record to the client Thanks for the help

Comment: The first glaring indicator that this answer is wrong is that it starts off by talking about URLs.  DNS does not work in terms of URLs, and a resolving proxy DNS server, like the questioner has, should perform all of the necessary back-end queries to construct a full answer for the front end.  Client libraries are _not_ expected to perform multiple front-end queries.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for being picky about an answer which is correct other then for saying URL for domain name - I'll change it.   Please also read ryans11 answer carefully - he confirms my answer was correct and helped him !

Comment: @JdeBP - RFC1035 - Section 3.3.1 states "CNAME RRs cause no additional section processing, but name servers may
choose to restart the query at the canonical name in certain cases.  See
the description of name server logic in [RFC-1034] for details."

Comment: @JdeBP Further, RFC1035 section 7.2 states "The resolver
will usually only have very strong hints about which servers to ask, in
the form of NS RRs, and may have to revise the query, in response to
CNAMEs, or revise the set of name servers the resolver is asking, in
response to delegation responses which point the resolver to name
servers closer to the desired information.

Comment: You don't understand how DNS servers work, plainly.  Sadly, the RFCs aren't going to help you, because they are easy to misunderstand, just as you have misunderstood them here.  That part of RFC1035 is describing the behaviour of a _content_ server, not of a server that performs the task of query resolution.  The jargon _name server_ in those RFCs has a very particular meaning, and it is not what you think it to be.

Comment: @JdeBP - For the sake of clarity section 2.1 confirms that the resolver is local to the end users device "From the user's point of view, domain names are useful as arguments to a
local agent, called a resolver, which retrieves information associated
with the domain name."

Comment: @JdeBP - Of-course not - I've only been a DNS administrator for ISP's for over 20 years - handling both authorative and recursive DNS.  I only have experience with BIND (including split dns, recursive only, authorative only), ProDNS, PureDNS

Comment: Then why on earth are you peddling rubbish about clients doing second lookups when you _must_ know better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74117/discussion-between-davidgo-and-jdebp).

Comment: @JdeBP I do not know better - what do you think RFC1035 means when section 7.2 says resolvers may have to revise the query, or revise the set of name servers they are asking ?
RFC 1035 does not use the term "content server" - Section 7 is titled "RESOLVER IMPLEMENTATION" - so its hard to believe its referring to content rather then resolvers.